# bootstrap dropdown menu in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using bootstrap for toogle down menu bar. The code is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it is not working properly. I'm facing the issue that whatever I'm displaying in these fields:

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"></a></li>
```

It is not visible.

Comment: Did you include the correct references to the bootstrap javascript and CSS files? Which browser(s) did you test in?

Comment: have you checked the bootstrap tutorial site [Bootstrap Examples C#](http://csharpexamples.com/bootstrap-examples/)

Comment: yes i am using the correct references .... I am testing in google chrome. I have checked your link , but it is of no help

Answer (score 2):

The items for the displaying are visible when I paste your code in my project. I think the problem is on your js. Try to add all the js for proper working of dropdown list.

Comment: This can rather be a comment and not an answer.